# Read all the JSON files from an IIS hosted Virtual Directory in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, iis, iis-7, angular-httpclient

I am working on an angular project where I have to read only JSON Files from a folder.
Folder is hosted as a Virtual Directory in IIS so I can access the folder with localhost:IP.
I cannot figure out how to find only JSON files from that specific folder and loop through them to fetch all the JSON file at once.

Though I can fetch one JSON file by giving its name also. But what if I don't know the name of file and I have to fetch all the JSON files from that location. Please help me out.

Comment: you can create a json with the name of the files (or is you're using a server an API or service that return this files name)

Comment: @Eliseo , 1st part I cannot do as there are 100 json files and to write name of every file won't be easy for me. And 2nd one , there is no server , just a physical path hosted on iis with all the files it may have other files also but i have to read all json files only

Comment: do you can not create a "script"? (I don't know if you're using windows or linux or Ios) It's out of my knowing but sure there're examples in internet